# System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng .NET Core

Tags: c#, azure, dll, .net-core, sha256

I have one .net core app as console and I'm trying to get some values from Azure Db. **This code works perfect on .NET Framework (standard) and I always get my data** but I need to work with .NET Core. In short, I have one method which GetConfig from another (.dll) and everytime I get exception:

[image: Exception]

```
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng' from assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.)'
```

I know .NET Core has System.Core but it doesn't have "SHA256Cng", just "SHA256". Maybe Can I use .net framework .dll or is there another way to solve this problem?
PS. Need to use only .NET Core (.net console app and other).

[image: Method]

```
public ITenantConfigurationProvider CreateTenantConfigurationProvider(ITenantClient client, string tenantId)
        {
            return client.GetConfigAsync(tenantId).Result;
        }
```

Comment: Do you have control on the ddl ? you need to change the reference inside the ddl to point to nuget package also. Because at the moment it tries to get the `SHA256Cng` from `System.Core` and with .net core the `SHA256Cng` is not in the `system.core` dll

Comment: Ok, how to do it ? I cannot find it :(

Answer (score 2):

Use `SHA256.Create()` instead of `new SHA256Cng()`

Comment: I note that in .NET Core (and not .NET Framework) the only guarantee is that the SHA-256 implementation will at least work, but there are no guarantees that `SHA256.Create()` will return the fastest possible implementation on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the SHA256 class is part of 'System.Security.Cryptography'. Do you have that library?

Comment: Yes, I do. Also I have installed other nuget packages such as algorithm, cryptography. Algorithm has SHA256Cng but MSDN says this "Sha" only in .net framework. If I cannot solve this I will be to get exception again. IDK why only .net framework standard has it. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to create a .NET framework project because .NET Core **does not support** this class.